# How do you access a value in a list of maps?

Tags: terraform

The value of `google_compute_subnetwork.subnetwork.secondary_ip_range` looks like this:

```
[
    {
        ip_cidr_range = 10.1.0.0/16,
        range_name = my-range
    }
]
```

I can't figure out how to loop over that, this doesn't work:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "sdfsdfsdf" {
 count = "${length(data.google_compute_subnetwork.mysubnetwork.secondary_ip_range)}"
 type      = "ingress"
 from_port    = 0
 to_port     = 0
 protocol    = "-1"
  cidr_blocks = ["${data.google_compute_subnetwork.mysubnetwork.secondary_ip_range[count.index]}.ip_cidr_range}"]
}
```

Comment: What does not work about it?

Answer (score 0):

the usage of `count.index` is in this document:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#element-list-index-

```
element(aws_subnet.foo.*.id, count.index)
```

So your code can be changed to

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "sdfsdfsdf" {
 count = "${length(data.google_compute_subnetwork.mysubnetwork.secondary_ip_range)}"
 type      = "ingress"
 from_port    = 0
 to_port     = 0
 protocol    = "-1"
  cidr_blocks = ["${element(data.google_compute_subnetwork.mysubnetwork.secondary_ip_range.*.ip_cidr_range, count.index)}"]
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the simpler `list[index]` syntax rather than `element` here.

Comment: this also does not work: `element: argument 1 should be type list, got type string in`. did this work for you? then if I try without brackets I get `element: argument 1 should be type list, got type string`

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Please always follow the latest official document, more than the way you worked it with old terraform version. Your way works, but not meaning it will be supported in the future.

Comment: @red888 How many `}` in your codes, in your post, the part of `cidr_blocks` , `{ }` are not properly paired.

Comment: What? `list[index]` is newer than `element()` and absolutely not deprecated.

Comment: Where is the document to use `list[index]`? I mean to use it in middle to replace `.*.`? and it is ugly code.

Comment: It replaces the `element` function (not strictly because it doesn't allow looping back through the list by using an index greater than the length of the list that `element` allows. It's documented [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#user-list-variables) and would mean that `element(provider_resource.name.*.output), index` becomes `provider_resource.name.*.output[index]`

Comment: No, the document you shared, that's not the style of `data.google_compute_subnetwork.mysubnetwork.secondary_ip_range.*.ip_cidr_range`, a `.*.` in between. In the same document, the element function gives the exact sample on how to handle this: `element(aws_subnet.foo.*.id, count.index)`. You need adjust your code, but seems you don't accept it is right way.